# How can I make my logo better

Tags: logo

This is a first draft for a nursery logo. I'm going for the neutral-ish palette but still a with a little bit of colour. The blocks need to stay as part of the logo as it is their current one, but the font and lettering can be changed. Ive transformed it a pastel palette to go with a website redesign. Any feedback or advice is appreciated.
Thank you!!

[image: original logo]

[image: first draft]

Comment: hi. Please edit your question so that the images are posted into the question body, not as links. This question will become irrelevant when your links expire, and this here is not a chat room. thanks

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. I’ve now adjusted it

Comment: Actually not bad logo, but yes you could try some other typefaces. This current font looks a bit wobbly.

Comment: Please edit your question to meet our [critique requirements](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/682)

Answer (score 1):

My opinion, I would still work on the text.
The blocks look nice, but the text feels like it's not from here.

Try changing the size or style, adding additional elements next to the text (shapes, images..).

In addition, you can combine blocks and text into one whole composition.
Below I have added examples for inspiration, I hope they will help you.
[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]